# Bootstrap navigation Iphone 12 PRO MAX

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap for a site and i'm having a strange problem with only the iPhone 12 Pro MAX, other devices(iphones) has no problems with it, the following screenshot is the problem:
[image]

- Red is the border color of the href.
- Black is the image border.

The following code that i use:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand " href="#"><img src="/themes/custom/images/logo-sm.png" class="img-responsive img-fluid mx-auto navbar-brand-bar"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="float: left;">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-bar-collapse-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link nav-active" href="/">link1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/link2">link2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/link3">link3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/link4">link4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Has somebody an explanation for this whats going wrong or is it just a bug in ios on this device?

Comment: `.navbar-brand` should be default on `display: inline-block`. Yours seems to be `display: block` or `flex`. Have you done something in CSS perhaps?

Comment: The navbar-brand isnt changed with CSS, really strange because its only on iPhone 12 Pro MAX and not on other devices.

Comment: After adding the width to 80%  onf the navbar-brand it works now for the iphone. what did happen was that the navigationbar/navigationicon was pust down below the logo instead next to the logo..